# Check a string for any items in an array

Tags: python

I have an string (items with comma separated) and I need to check if any of the items in the string (or list after split) are present in a long string.

I know how to do this in a long style like:

```
people="first,second"
test='hello_first'

for i in people.split(","):
    if i in test :
          print 'found'
```

Is there a better way to combine `for` and `if` in one line ?

e.g. using `any` or something?

```
if any(x in people.split(",") for x in test) :
    print 'found'
```

doesn't seem to print 'found'.

Comment: Are you wanting a method to combine `for` and `if` or are you wanting to get your `for` loop with nested `if` statement working properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any checking if any word  is in test :

```
if any(word in test for word in people.split(",")):
   # do whatever
```

Your logic is incorrect as you are checking test is in the split list of words which does not match your first loop.

Comment: note that this isn't exactly identical to the original nested loop, since that loop will run `print 'found'` N times (where N is now many elements in `people.split(',')` are present in `test`.

Comment: @AdamSmith, the OP wants to know if any word matches, they were just using any wrong as per their second snippet

Comment: Oh I agree, I'm just pointing out the difference between the example code and the result code. What OP wants to do is almost certainly this (even if he doesn't know it!!)

Comment: Don't you need to use `test.split("_")` to get the words in the input string?

Comment: @Barmar,  the OP is testing if any word after splitting people on a comma  is in the string. *I need to check if any of the items in the string (or list after split) are present in a long string.* If they wanted to avoid match `first` in  `hello_firsts` yes they would need to split but maybe `_` could be anything, if so the correct solution would be a regex with word boundaries.