# I can't call upon my variable which contains several words in it (if in variable:)

Tags: python

I am trying to call upon a variable I created for an 'if' statement in Python. 
Here is a summed up version:

```
yes = ("yes", "y")
question1 = input("Am I right?")
if question1.lower() in yes:
print ("you are correct")
```

but I get an error :

```
--'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not builtin_function_or_method
```

My actual code is quite odd, but here you go ((it isn't for the feint of heart)):

```
yes = ["yes", "y"]
m = "men"
w = "women"
badkeywordslist = ["depression", "pain", "hurt", "dead", "die", "kill", "hell", "suffering", "cutting", "cut", "death"]

Question1 = input("We will start off simple, what is your name?")
if len(Question1) > 0 and Question1.isalpha():
    Question2 =  input("Ah! Lovely name, %s. Not surprised you get all the women, or is it men?" % Question1)
    if Question2.lower() in m:
        print ("So, your name is %s and you enjoy the pleasure of %s! I bet you didnt see that coming." % (Question1, Question2))
    elif Question2.lower() in w:
        print ("So, your name is %s and you enjoy the pleasure of %s! I bet you didnt see that coming." % (Question1, Question2))
    else:
        print ("Come on! You're helpless. I asked you a simple question with 2 very destinctive answers. Restart!")
else:
    print ("Come on, enter your accurate information before proceeding! Restart me!")
Question3 = input("Now I know your name and what gender attracts you. One more question and I will know everything about you... Shall we continue?")
if Question3.lower() in yes:
    Question4 = input("Well, it's quite simple really. What's good in your life and what's bad?")
    if Question4 in badkeywordslist:
        print ("Oh... So your life isn't going so great now, is it? For starters, are you safe?")
```

Comment: Show your *actual* code.

Comment: What you posted right now is correct code that will work fine in Python 3 as long as you properly indent that last print statement inside your conditional statement. If you are using Python 2 you should change that input to raw_input.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `.lower()`, not `.lower`?

Comment: Hmm. I will send you my actual code @MarkRansom and thank you I am using Python 3, it just seems to not be working.

Comment: Will you please also add the full stack trace?

Comment: @MarkRansom That is a copy of my code. I can't call on "badkeywordslist" when I try to. I run the program and everything works great and when I Reach the end, it does nothing. It wont relate the user input to the badkeywordslist

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist What do you mean? I am new, sorry

Comment: `--'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not builtin_function_or_method` <-- add everything above this that shows exactly what line where the error occurs. Reading this should be the first thing you do when you're trying to figure out what's going wrong, and you will often need to post it here for the same reason.

Comment: I tried your script and didn't get any errors.

Comment: Learn more about [ask] and creating [MCVE].

Comment: The test for bad keywords doesn't test each word in their input. It just compares the whole line with the bad words. So if they write "I want to kill someone" it won't match, they have to type just "kill".

Comment: @Barmar The problem isnt an error, when you get to the end, type a word or key phrase from the 
badkeywordslist = ["depression", "pain", "hurt", "dead", "die", "kill", "hell", "suffering", "cutting", "cut", "death"]
If you do, it doesn't follow the rest of the code on like 23

Comment: @Barmar Ah, thank you! Is there a way to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174119/check-a-string-for-any-items-in-an-array/37174142#37174142

Comment: @Barmar okay, thank you I will do that. Now, can you tell me what I did wrong when asking this question so that I get it right next time? haha

Comment: You said you got an error, but the actual code doesn't get that error, so it's a completely different problem. And you never explained clearly what the script is supposed to do. Where in the question does it say that it's supposed to check each word in the answer against the list of bad keywords? All the other places where you use `variable in list` you're just checking a single word.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I will make my next questions more concise and looked over. I appreciate it guys!

Comment: @Barmar I followed the link and I didn't understand the answer :( I simply want to check the user input against an array...

Comment: That's exactly what they're doing in the question I linked to. `people.split(",")` is the array to check against, and `test` is the user input.

Comment: @barmar Okay, thank you! Got it!! (:

Answer (score -1):

In python 2.x; 
you must use `raw_input` instead of `input` as 
`input()` actually evaluates the input as Python code.
`raw_input()` returns the verbatim string entered by the user.

```
yes = ("yes", "y")
question1 = raw_input("Am I right?")
if question1.lower() in yes:
    print("you are correct")
```

Just tried your code on https://www.codechef.com/ide and its perfectly fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Python 3.x! :( I did know that however, I appreciate it!

Comment: This is not tagged Python 2 and that would throw a totally different error anyway.

Comment: I didn't see any errors then except the print function indentation.

Comment: Please re-check your input as you may be entering a newline character; or something that might not be perceived as a string.