# Check if user input contains a word from an array - Python 3

Tags: python

I am writing a code that asks a set amount of questions. 
I am trying to have the user input an answer and the code checks the users input for any word in a list of several words.

```
keywordlist = ("pain", "suffering", "hurt")
question1 = input("how are you feeling?")
if question1.lower() in keywordlist:
    print("something here")
```

I ended up browsing stackoverflow for the answer and came across a post about splitting a string, but I didn't understand it. It was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174119/check-a-string-for-any-items-in-an-array/37174142#37174142) question.

using this link I switched my code to :

```
if any(word in Question1 for word in keywordlist.split(",")):
```

but I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I am new to Python and need the dumbed down version of the accurate way to do this.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @AndrewL. because a tuple is more correct than a list here, the values are not meant to be changed.

Comment: @karlosss what do you mean?

Comment: The error you have posted is inconsistent with the code you have posted.

Comment: @Gu-- as long as Python has no constants, it uses tuples as "immutable lists". So you are correct with your keyword list definition, what @AndrewL. suggested was doing `kwlist=["pain", "suffering", "hurt"]`

Comment: I have found the answer below. Sorry for not accurately asking the question, but what was wrong is that the user could answer question1 with "I am suffering" and the print statement wouldnt work. 
it asks "how are you feeling" and if you said "hurt" it wouldnt follow through with the print statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the user to input a sentence and want to check if any word is in the keyword list:

```
keywordlist = ("pain", "suffering", "hurt")
question1 = input("how are you feeling?")
input_words=question1.lower().split()
for word in input_words:
    if word in keywordlist:
        print("something here")
```

The reason `if any(word in Question1 for word in keywordlist.split(",")):` gave you that error is because you called the `split()` method on `keywordlist` which is a tuple. So the error is telling you exactly what you did wrong. You want to split the input into words, the `keywordlist` already contains words split up into a tuple.

Comment: THANK YOU!! That is the dumbed down version I was looking for haha I appreciate it! Thumbs up (: Both the methods posted on this question worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the string should work. You can split on spaces so each individual word ends up being an element in a list. Like so

```
keywordlist = ("pain", "suffering", "hurt")
question1 = input("how are you feeling?")
question_parts = question1.split(" ")
for part in question_parts:
    if part.lower() in keywordlist:
        print("something here")
```

Comment: To add to this reply; if the user inputs "I am suffering", when you `split()` the input, it will end up in a list like `("I", "am", "suffering")`, thus you can iterate on it and confirm if each word is in your `keywordlist`

Comment: Okay so, this actually worked. I placed it in my actual code which is very similar to the one I used for reference, the problem is: 
If you reply to question1 with more than one of the key words like "I am in pain and I hurt a lot" it will print "something here" two times...